# passing structs into function by reference in C code (compilation error)

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference

Is there anything wrong with this?
According to the compiler there is an error in this line

```
void memory_allocation(struct a *s1,struct b *s2,struct c *s3,int size)
```

main looks like

```
main()
{   
    struct mystack
    {
        int head;
        void **stack;
        void **stackcopy;
        int stack_size;

    } *ptr ; 

    struct professor
    {
        char flag;
        char surname[50];
        char coursbhe[50];
    } *prof;

    struct student
    {
        char flag;
        char surname[50];
        int semester;
    } *stud;

    (*ptr).stack_size=getstacksize();
        memory_allocation(&ptr,&prof,&stud,(*ptr).stack_size);

}
```

Comment: how are structs a, b and c defined?

Comment: `void memory_allocation(struct a *s1,struct b *s2,struct c *s3,int size)` : Different type. and `ptr` not initialize.

Comment: why do u want to pass address of pointer into the function _memory_allocation_? Try passing it without the & symbol

Comment: because if i use malloc to allocate memory in the function without passing the address of the pointer there will be no memory allocated for the structs in main so i have to use double pointers.That s how i know it works,no?

Comment: Your types are local to the function (`main()`) in which they are defined.  That means you cannot reliably pass variables of those types to any other function.  You should define the types outside of main so that other functions can use the same types.  There is a concept of type equivalence, but there's also a concept called DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  The only way another function could use those types is by writing them out again, repeating yourself.  Don't!

Comment: I mustn't use global variables.

Comment: Defining types at global scope doesn't create any global variables.  It is good discipline not to use global variables, but it is a mistake to think that types are variables.

Comment: when u pass a pointer to a function, it is equivalent to passing by reference. I believe there is no need of using & in your function. Also using & will violate your function declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your types are local to the function (`main()`) in which they are defined. That means you cannot reliably pass variables of those types to any other function. You should define the types outside of `main()` so that other functions can use the same types. There is a concept of type equivalence, but there's also a concept called DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself. The only way another function could use those types is by writing them out again, repeating yourself. Don't!

Your types need to be available outside the function.  You don't have to define any global variables when you define the types.  For example, you could use:

```
struct mystack
{
    int head;
    void **stack;
    void **stackcopy;
    int stack_size;
};

struct professor
{
    char flag;
    char surname[50];
    char coursbhe[50];
};

struct student
{
    char flag;
    char surname[50];
    int semester;
};

extern int getstacksize(void);
extern void memory_allocation(struct stack **s1, struct professor **s2,
                              struct student **s3, int size);
extern void memory_release(struct stack *stack, struct professor *prof,
                           struct student *stud);

int main(void)
{   
    struct mystack *ptr = 0; 
    struct professor *prof = 0;
    struct student *stud = 0;
    int stack_size = getstacksize();
    memory_allocation(&ptr, &prof, &stud, stack_size);
    memory_release(ptr, prof, stud);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the memory allocation function cannot do anything useful unless:

1. It knows about the types of the structures it is to allocate.
2. It is passed pointers to the pointers so it can modify the actual pointers in the `main()`.
3. The memory release function doesn't need pointer to pointer syntax, though it could be used and if it was used, the memory release function should set the pointed at pointers to NULL when the memory is released to minimize the risk of abusing already freed memory.

The additional variable `stack_size` is needed because `ptr` doesn't point to anything when `getstacksize()` is called, so referencing `(*ptr).stack_size` will probably crash and definitely not work correctly.  Alternatively, you could change the definition of the variable to `stack mystack stack;` and then use `stack.stack_size = getstacksize();` and pass `stack.stack_size` to the allocation function, but then you don't need the memory allocator to allocate the stack as a whole any more.  Separation of duty suggests that there will be a separate function to allocate the stack internals.

All the material from the first `struct mystack` line down to but not including `int main(void)` is eligible to be put into a header so that the implementation of the functions can see the same type and function definitions as the `main()` program can see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution....
use your prototype of function as below

**void memory_allocation(struct mystack  *s1 , struct professor *s2 , struct student *s3 , int d)**

because you are calling with defined struct not other and call should be like

**memory_allocation(ptr,prof,stud,(*ptr).stack_size);**

remove "&" sign or remove *s1 to s1(have to pass address ,not address of address)

please change both things, it will work,my side its working..